# Can you setup an application to be only Javascript on the client side and PHP on a remote server?

Tags: php, javascript, sql-server-2008, api, extjs4

We are planning the architecture of an enterprise application that will reside behind the firewall on the clients server. We would like to stick with PHP for the server side language and extjs for the client side. Although, we do not want the client to be required to install Apache, etc on their windows machine. There are a few ideas that I have for the architecture although I would like to know if I can accomplish packaging the application for download for the client and all it contains is the Javascript and communicates with our single server instance for server side computations? I believe this can be done best with an API. Our clients use MSQL Server 2008 on Windows servers and about 10% of them are allowed to run linux on a virtual machine.

Is this correct? Your thoughts and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: "with an API" is not how you describe an architecture.

Comment: What would the client actually _see_ when they use this application? Would it have a UI or run as a background task?

Comment: Yes, the client would see the UI in their browser. Because of industry regulations they are not able to use internal applications that are not hosted on their internal server behind their firewall. So we need to provide them a package they can configure and access through internal URLs. The rest of our application will be written in PHP (preferred). But we do not want them to have to install WAMP or any Apache stack in order to access the application in their browser. It would be great if Extjs was able to access Mysql without PHP or reading and writing JSON data directly to the database.

Comment: ExtJS can store data to HTML5's local storage - but clients won't be able to share data between them as the database is actually part of each client browser. You cannot have PHP or MySql without some form of a server installed (or Zend or similar products).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is - yes you can.

ExtJS is a javascript library. As such it requires a browser to run, not a server.

You can write a whole application with ExtJs such as one that will be downloaded and run on any PC browser (or Chromebook) - without any server installation being involved.

If you wish your clients to download the client-side application - no problems (they will simply have to open an index file on their browser). But you can equally just put the javascript files on your server and refer your users to the corresponding url, so you can update the code of your app easily, without your clients needing to constantly download updates. Your clients still won't need any apache or server installed.

ExtJs allows server communication, the nature of which is irrelevant (it can run PHP over apache, ASP.net, RubyOnRail, anything).

Comment: Our particular clients are not allowed to use our application in the cloud outside of their internal network perimeter. So they would have to host it. We rather use PHP for our server side language although it requires Apache. We do not want the client to have to install Apache or do much server configuration outside of configuration and setup of the application MSSQL database, domain mapping, and AD integration. After some research I was thinking in order to accomplish building a complete js application with SilkJS and ExtJS accompanied by the client's desired database (MSSQL or MySQL)

Comment: So the server will be within the Intranet, or outside it via a firewall?